# SSLEngine: Invalid TLS padding data when unwrapping after a successful handshake

Tags: java, rest, http, ssl, sslengine

I am using non-blocking socketChannel and SSLEngine an ssl server. So after a successfull handshake, i read the socket ( 184 bytes /384 bytes are being read in the first time), and then i pass this buffer to unwrap method. The unwrap method throw the following exception :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid TLS padding data
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
```

But in case I read all the bytes (384/384) in the first time, then I don't get this exception.

I thought that if the sslengine doesn't have enough byte to unwrap it will return a bufferUnderflow status.

Do I really need all bytes to call unwrap method? If yes how can I be sure I read all bytes for the non blocking socket?

---

EDIT: the code:

```
public boolean doHandShake(SocketChannel socket) throws Exception{

        if(!socket.isConnected()){
            return false;
        }

        outAppData.clear();
        inAppData.clear();
        inNetData.clear();
        outNetData.clear();

        if(engine==null || socket==null)
         return false;


          engine.beginHandshake();
          SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus hs = engine.getHandshakeStatus();

          while (hs != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.FINISHED &&
                    hs != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING) {

              switch (hs) {

              case NEED_UNWRAP:
                   int read=1;
                  while (read > 0) {
                            read=socket.read(inNetData);
                            if(read==-1){
                                throw new IOException ("channel closed");
                            }
                        }

                  inNetData.flip();
                  engineRes=engine.unwrap(inNetData, outAppData);
                  inNetData.compact();

                  switch(engineRes.getStatus()){
                            case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                                System.out.println("overFlow");
                                break;
                            case CLOSED:
                                return false;
                            case OK:
                                //outAppData.clear();
                            //  inNetData.clear();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                  }

              break;

              case NEED_WRAP :
                 outNetData.clear();
                  engineRes=engine.wrap(inAppData, outNetData);
                  outNetData.flip();
                  switch (engineRes.getStatus()){
                            case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                                System.out.println("overFlow");
                                break;
                            case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                                System.out.println("underFlowa");
                                break;
                            case CLOSED:
                                return false;
                            case OK:
                                //outNetData.flip();
                                while(outNetData.hasRemaining()){
                                    if(socket.write(outNetData)<0){
                                        throw new Exception("Channel Has been Closed");
                                    }
                                }

                                break;
                            default:
                                break;


                  }

              break;

              case NEED_TASK :
                  Runnable r=engine.getDelegatedTask();
                  r.run();
                  break;

              case FINISHED:
                  System.out.println("finished");
                    break;

              case NOT_HANDSHAKING:
                    break;

                  default: 
                      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Inexpected/Unhadled SSLEngineResult :"+hs);

              }

              hs = engine.getHandshakeStatus();

          }
          return true;

    }
```

then I read 184/384 bytes using non blocking channel.

read = _socketChannel.read(buffer);

and then pass the to `buffer` to be decrypted:

```
public ByteBuffer decrypt(ByteBuffer inNetData) throws SSLException{

        if(!isValidSession()){
            return null;
        }
            outAppData.clear();

            try{
              engineRes=engine.unwrap(inNetData, outAppData);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              inNetData.compact();

              switch(engineRes.getStatus()){
                    case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                        outAppData=ByteBuffer.allocate(outNetData.capacity()*2);
                        inNetData.position(0);
                        return encrypt(inNetData);
                    case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                        return null;
                    case CLOSED:
                        return null;
                    case OK:
                        outAppData.flip();
                        System.out.println(new String(outAppData.array(),0,400));

                        return outAppData;
                    default:
                        break;
              }


        return null;
    }
```

the exception is being thrown in engine.unwrap
engineRes=engine.unwrap(inNetData, outAppData);

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here.

1. If you get `BUFFER_OVERFLOW` you must `flip(), write(), compact(),` and repeat the `wrap()`. Not just print it and give up as above.
2. If you get `BUFFER_UNDERFLOW` you must read() and repeat the unwrap(). This is your specific problem.
3. If you get an `Exception` of any kind it isn't sufficient to just print the exception and continue as though it hadn't happened.
4. `FINISHED` is never returned by `getHandshakeStatus()`. It is only ever set in the handshake status in the `SSLEngineResult` that is returned by `wrap()` and `unwrap()`.
5. You are calling `encrypt()` from within the `decrypt()` method. This doesn't make sense.
6. Your overall technique won't work. A handshake can happen any time, in the middle of a read or write, and you have to write your code so as to cope with that. When you've succeeded in that, you won't need to call your own `doHandshake()` method at all, as your code will cope with it anyway.

The SSLEngine is a state machine. You must do exactly what it tells you to do.

Comment: yep i know the try chatch block was just to show the exception is being thrown by unwrap(). My question was, why when i pass to unwrap() 184 bytes out of 384 it throws an exeception instead of pointing to bufferunderflow??? and why when i pass 384 byte out of 384 it is working well??

Comment: in my case: unwrap method throws an exception and doesn't return the BUFFER_UNDERFLOW when number of bytes is not enough